# Migrating from wordpress.com to wordpress -> [googlemaps] and [youtube] shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

I migrated my blog from wordpress.com to the actual wordpress software. I have [googlemaps] and [youtube] shortcode (think that's the right term) inserted in the pages, yet I can't find the same shortcode plugin that will let me do this. Anyone know where to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps shortcode plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-map-shortcode/
Youtube shortcode plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-brackets/